# Scala: How to make the return type of function generic and dependent on runtime arguments?

Tags: scala, reflection, polymorphism

Say I have:

```
class Animal
class Bird extends Animal
class Dog extends Animal
```

How can I write a function that returns the runtime type (Bird or Dog) depending on the provided arguments.

I'm trying something like:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def createAnimal[T <: Animal : ClassTag](doesItBark: Boolean): T = {
    if (doesItBark) return new Dog()
    else return new Bird()
}


val azor = createAnimal(doesItBark = true) //azor's type should be Dog
```

Which doesn't work.

Is it possible to do something like this in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether this is possible or not depends a lot on how you define the problem. It's not too hard to write something very similar with a custom type class:

```
class Animal
class Bird extends Animal
class Dog extends Animal

sealed trait ChooseAnimal[A <: Animal] { def createAnimal: A }

val isBarker: ChooseAnimal[Dog] = new ChooseAnimal[Dog] {
  def createAnimal: Dog = new Dog
}

val isNotBarker: ChooseAnimal[Bird] = new ChooseAnimal[Bird] {
  def createAnimal: Bird = new Bird
}

def createAnimal[A <: Animal](choose: ChooseAnimal[A]): A =
  choose.createAnimal
```

And then:

```
scala> createAnimal(isBarker)
res0: Dog = Dog@25cd1055

scala> createAnimal(isNotBarker)
res1: Bird = Bird@1f4e89bc
```

Note the appropriate static types. This isn't exactly what you asked for, but it's pretty similar. If you actually want to use `Boolean` as the selector, you'll need something like [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```
import shapeless._

trait ChooseBarker[B <: Boolean, A <: Animal] { def createAnimal: A }

implicit val barker: ChooseBarker[Witness.`true`.T, Dog] =
  new ChooseBarker[Witness.`true`.T, Dog] { def createAnimal: Dog = new Dog }

implicit val nonBarker: ChooseBarker[Witness.`false`.T, Bird] =
  new ChooseBarker[Witness.`false`.T, Bird] { def createAnimal: Bird = new Bird }

def createAnimal[B <: Boolean, A <: Animal](w: Witness.Aux[B])(implicit
  choose: ChooseBarker[B, A]
): A = choose.createAnimal
```

And then:

```
scala> createAnimal(true)
res0: Dog = Dog@46c09af6

scala> createAnimal(false)
res1: Bird = Bird@186b9fc2
```

Again we get the right static types.

This approach still has some limitations—e.g. if the argument isn't a literal, you'll have to be sure you've got a `Witness` instance for it—but it's close enough to what you're asking for that I don't think we should just say that this kind of thing is impossible.

---

It's worth noting that you can even do without the type parameters if you really want to:

```
import shapeless._

sealed trait ChooseBarker[B] extends DepFn0 { type Out <: Animal }

object ChooseBarker {
  type Aux[B, A <: Animal] = ChooseBarker[B] {
    type Out = A
  }

  def mk[B, A <: Animal](a: A): Aux[B, A] = new ChooseBarker[B] {
    type Out = A

    def apply(): A = a
  }

  implicit val barker: Aux[Witness.`true`.T, Dog] = mk(new Dog)
  implicit val nonBarker: Aux[Witness.`false`.T, Bird] = mk(new Bird)
}

def createAnimal(w: Witness)(implicit choose: ChooseBarker[w.T]): choose.Out =
  choose()
```

And then:

```
scala> val dog: Dog = createAnimal(true)
dog: Dog = Dog@1681d515

scala> val bird: Bird = createAnimal(false)
bird: Bird = Bird@76634045
```

This all works thanks to the magic of path-dependent types.

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible. The return type of a method must be known at compile time, i.e. that it returns type `T`. However, the type parameter `T` must be determined when the method is called, *and not after*. The caller must know the type before-hand, so best thing you can do here is return `Animal`.

```
val newAnimal: ??? = createAnimal(runtimeParam)
           //   ^ What type goes here? 
           //     The compiler needs to infer it, but it can't that way
```

Therefore, when calling `createAnimal` you need to be expect a `Dog`, `Bird`, or `Animal`. And since you don't know what that might be, you can only say it's an `Animal`. You can then later use a type-test to check what you got back, if necessary.

The type parameter won't do anything unless you fill it in, yourself. Otherwise, you should just have:

```
def createAnimal(doesItBark: Boolean): Animal = {
    if (doesItBark) return new Dog()
    else return new Bird()
}
```

Comment: "Impossible" is a little too strong, I think.